# CSS gradient-fade/disappear adjacent to an element

Tags: css, gradient

I have a footer element and I'd like to fade all content above it, as follows:

> scrollable mixed content (should be normal/solid on top)
>
> scrollable mixed content (should transition to transparent here)
>
> ---
>
> fixed-position, solid, footer

The "mixed content" could be anything, there's no set background color. I'm trying to blend or mask the content so it fades to transparent as it approaches the footer boundary.

I don't think it's possible with a footer background image or webkit-mask because that relies on a fixed background color for the mixed content. The only idea I had was putting all the mixed content in a fixed container element and using a mask on the bottom of it, but that's complicated and slows everything down.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/